# Sharing the same data area in JAVA multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading

It is said that, if a class is implemented Runnabe interface, it can be turned into a thread, whose instances can share the same data area in the class. However, there is only run() method in Runnable interface, so how is this realized?

Comment: add `implements Runnable` to your class, implement the `run()` method, access your instance fields from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@La Kate, the sharing happens in a concrete class that `implements Runnable`. Such a class will have *state*, that is, fields that hold information about the `Runnable` instance. These fields are shared between every thread that uses the exact same `Runnable` instance. This is unlike the mistaken `extends Thread` idiom, where each thread has its own separate state.

So for example:

```
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  final Object lock = new Object();

  final ImportantInfo info = new ImportantInfo();

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      doABunchOfStuff();
      synchronized (lock) {
          info.load();
      }
      doABunchOfOtherStuff();
    }
  }
};
```

This `Runnable` instance can be sent to more than one `Thread`:

```
Thread footh = new Thread(runnable);
Thread barth = new Thread(runnable);
footh.start();
barth.start();
```

The two threads use the exact same `Runnable`, so that means each thread now shares state via the immutable `lock` object and the mutable `info` object. The former can synchronize access, and the latter can pass changes between threads.

Answer (score 0):

> However, there is only run() method in Runnable interface, so how is
>   this realized?

This is realized by introducing state in your runnables and then passing on same instances for those state objects. A runnable with no state doesn't share data.

Below is not a running or compiling code but just to give you a rough idea - there are two threads sharing a `Student` object. `private Student student;` introduces state to your runnable.

```
public class ExampleRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Student student;
    public void ExampleRunnable(Student student){
     this.student=student;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
     .....do something with student here in synchronized way....
     .....
    }
```

and below is class where you create threads ,

```
public class MainClass {
      public static void main(String[] args){
      Student student = new Student();

      Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ExampleRunnable(student));
      Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ExampleRunnable(student));

      /* So in above code, there are two different runnables and two different threads but both are using same Student object . This way you can share data among various runnables / threads. */
    }
    }
        }
```

Comment: `ExampleRunnable#student` should be `final`, and one could share the `Runnable` instance itself.

Answer (score -1):

In fact the Runnable interface provides only a method to turn an object into a thread (it is an interface) it's not a structure to share variables, these objects can share variables using the "synchronized" modifier or other thread safe structures (you can find it in the oracle guide), but this is up to you.

Comment: This doesn't explain here how the instances share data, as the OP asked.